# What is the Topology of Cantor set as the subset of real line with standard euclidean topology?

Tags: general-topology

It may be an odd question.  But, I particularly want to know the open's of cantor set with inherited topology of real line.

Comment: The question isn’t entirely clear. As @zibadawatimmy’s link points out, up to homeomorphism open subset of $C$ is homeomorphic either to $C$ or to $C\setminus\{p\}$ for any $p\in C$, and the latter is fairly easily shown to be homeomorphic to $\Bbb N\times C$. This is a complete answer if you simply want to classify the open subsets of $C$ up to homeomorphism. If you want some sort of explicit identification of them, however, you’ll not do much better than ‘they’re the intersections with $C$ of open sets in $\Bbb R$’.

Comment: This is clearly NOT a duplicate of that other question.  "Duplicate" should mean it's asking the same thing, so that any answer to either would be suitable as an answer to the other.

Comment: The topology is the same as the product topology on $\{0,1\}^{\aleph_0}$, which is the same as the topology of pointwise convergence.  Every open subset of $\{0,1\}^{\aleph_0}$ is the set of all $0$-$1$ sequences with a finite number of terms specified.  Maybe later I'll post a proof of that below if no one else does. ${}\qquad{}$